# A solvable Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> My prefix is one that can be just plain rude,
>  To get my infix, I think you may need
>   to brood.
>  My suffix can be seen in the actions of angry dudes
>
> All in all, I am something that 'eats food'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> Dissolvent

My prefix is one that can be just plain rude,

> **Dis** = speak disrespectfully to or criticize.

To get my infix, I think you may need to brood.

> **Solve**, you may need to brood in order to solve a problem

My suffix can be seen in the actions of angry dudes

> **Vent** = let out a strong and sometimes angry emotion.

All in all, I am something that 'eats food'

> A bit loose but the concept of dissolving could be seen as metaphorical for 'eating food'.

Title

> This really is what put me on this track, the connection between the words **solvable** and **dissolvent**.

Comment: You are completely correct, especially the part about eating food, I was trying to make it all rhyme and it was the best fit.